# Abkürzungen mit Bindestrich

Tags: abbreviation, hyphen

Sollte ein "Trans-Atlantic Data Privacy Framework" mit T-ADPF oder TADPF abgekürzt werden?

Gibt es dafür Regelungen/Vereinbarungen?

Comment: Ist es eine gute Idee, in einem Forum, das sich mit deutscher Sprache beschäftigt, nach einer englischen Abkürzung zu fragen? In einer englischen Truppe wär' die Frage sicher besser aufgehoben. Nachdem aber TTIP (das auch ein "trans-atlantic" im Bauch hat), keinen Bindestrich in der Abkürzung hat...

Comment: @tofro Legitimer Hinweis, danke!

Comment: https://www.anwalt.de/rechtstipps/trans-atlantic-data-privacy-framework-tadpf-199183.html. Aber Du solltest die Frage löschen, mit deutscher Sprache hat das nicht zu tun.

Comment: @Kritiker_der_Elche: Auch englische Abkürzungen können Teil eines deutschen Texts sein. Oder sprichst Du auf Deutsch immer von "ÜSAV/ZNAV" (Übertragungssteuerungsablaufvereinbarung/Zwischennetzablaufsvereinbarung) anstatt von "TCP/IP" (Transport Control Protocol/Internet Protocol)? Falls Letzteres der Fall ist, dann ist die Frage, wie man es korrekterweise schreibt, auch legitim und hat durchaus mit deutscher Sprache zu tun.

Comment: @bakunin Wenn deine Prämisse stimmen würde, müsste man TCP/IP im Sinne der Frage als T-C-P/I-P im Deutschen abkürzen.

Comment: @tofro: Wieso? Die Frage fragt doch gerade, was man schreiben soll. Wenn es irgendein Argument für das eine oder andere (in deutschen Texten) gibt, wäre das eine Antwort auf die Frage.

Comment: Ich werde diese Frage nicht migrieren, da es durchaus legitim ist zu fragen, wie englische Abkürzungen in deutschen Texten zu schreiben sind – selbst wenn die Antwort ist, dass alles wie im Englischen ist. Bis auf gegenläufige Klarstellung des Fragestellers würde ich davon ausgehen, dass genau danach gefragt ist.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Nach derselben Logik gehören hier dann auch Fragen hin, wie man Chinesische *Wörter* in deutschen Texten schreiben oder (noch ein bißchen übersteigert) Italienische Renaissance--Bilder in deutschen Büchern kolorieren soll - Das erscheint mir nicht sehr zielführend.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn es zum Beispiel um die Wahl zwischen verschiedenen Transkriptionssystemen geht, sehe ich kein Problem mit der Frage zur Schreibung chinesischer Wörter. Es gibt sogar offizielle Rechtschreibregeln bezüglich englischer Zusammensetzungen in deutschen Texten (§37, E3–4). Wieso die italienischen Bilder vergleichbar sein sollen, verschließt sich mir aber.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Weil du argumentierst, dass etwas. sobald es in einem deutschen Text vorkommt, egal welche anderen Kenntnisse eines fremden Fachgebiets (und mir ist das vollkommen egal, ob das *englische Sprache* oder *italienische Renaissance-Malerei* ist) es auch erfordern möge, hierherpasst.

Comment: @tofro: Mein Punkt ist ja gerade, dass es (a priori) nicht um Kenntnisse eines anderen Fachgebiets geht, da das Deutsche nicht notwendigerweise englische Begriffe genauso abkürzt wie das Englische. Natürlich kann es sein, dass die Antwort lautet, dass man die entsprechende Abkürzung im Englischen übernimmt, und [english.se] oder [ell.se] dürfen dann beantworten, welche dies ist, aber bis zu dem Punkt ist es eine Frage über die deutsche Sprache.

Comment: @tofro: Der Unterschied zwischen der "Kolorierung italienischer Renaissance-Malerei" in deutschen Büchern und der Frage, welche Regeln für englischsprachige Abkürzungen in denselben (bzw. Texten allgemein) gelten ist doch der, daß die Kolorierung keine Frage der Sprache (sondern vielleicht eine der Typographie, des Satzes oder was auch immer) ist. Ob man "Renaissance-Malerei" richtigerweise aber mit Bindestrich oder ohne schreibt, diese Frage sollte man hier schon stellen dürfen, oder?

Answer (score 5):

Nach meinem Sprachempfinden verbindet ein Bindestrich **ausgeschriebene** Wörter enger miteinander. Das gilt in der deutschen wie in der englischen Sprache.

In einer **Abkürzung** dagegen erzeugt der Bindestrich gefühlt eher eine Abgrenzung der Teile, würde also "T-ADPF" eher in zwei Teile "T" und "ADPF" trennen. Und das passt nicht, es würde ja ein "Atlantic Data Privacy Framework" mit dem Attribut "Trans" belegen, als gäbe es mehrere "Atlantic Data Privacy Frameworks", und "Trans" wäre eines davon.

Wenn eine Abkürzung notwendig wäre, würde ich "TADPF" wählen.